# HTML Multilevel Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have some trouble making a search form that can be used for real estate. The user should type/select a city or  can just type/select his region or country for wider search results (estates from the whole region) as shown below:

[image: Example]

It can be done with `<select> <optgroup> <option>` but `<optgroup>` is not clickable and I have a lot of data (2700 cities), so Ajax/Jquery is probably the best way to do this.

Are there any plugins/ways to help me achieve this with just one  form input?

Comment: try an autocomplete or typeahead plugin

Comment: Take a look at jQuery UI. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be "Chosen" jQuery plugin http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#optgroup-support (optgroup paragraph)?

Comment: I found this example of choosen jquery : http://jsfiddle.net/slothbear/9xqpF/ . I try it. thanks for the tips guys